# Code First connection string

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I have an error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException' occurred in DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection.

In DataAccess project I have an EF 6 with App.Config file with string:

```
<connectionStrings>  <add name="CVJobOnlineEntities"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model 1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=STEFAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CVJobOnline;integrated  security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

and in my second project, which is the main Start-Up project I have in WebConfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CVJobOnlineEntities"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CVJobOnline;Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

So, obviously I am mixing EDMX and CodeFirst conn strings, but, I need it CodeFirst because of my Identity tables which I was incorporate in my SQL SERVER DB.

Also in my DbContext, I recalled base to use FirstCode (Model1.Context.cs):

```
 public partial class CVJobOnlineEntities : DbContext
{
    public CVJobOnlineEntities()
        : base("name=CVJobOnlineEntities")
    {
    }
```

Comment: Why are u making the identity tables in the same database??

Comment: Why not just add the identity tables to your model and use model-first for all tables? The alternative is to create a separate context class (e.g. `IdentityEntities`) and use that one in code-first style.

Comment: For better maintaining? is it a better solution to leave Identity tables on default conn string (localdb), and all other data to pull from another conn string?Is that doable?

Comment: yes. make them into another database.. localdb is good enough for getting started..

Comment: @Abbondanza I did that. In my Context I can see clearly my Identity tables. So, you want to tell me that to put just EDMX conn string in the web config and that should do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify your connection string only once at the entry point of your application. Your `DataAccess` project does not need a connection string if it is not executable. Cut & paste the connection string from your `DataAccess` project to the web configuration file of your application entry point, overwriting the old one.

The problem was not exactly *mixing* two types of connection strings, since the one from `DataAccess` was never read by the Entity Framework. The one provided at your entry point config was just wrong in your scenario, because you are using model-first and not code-first.

Comment: Great explanation! For now, I let it default conn - for user data, and the other conn string for all other data.